# Calling Groovy or Java from JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, groovy, dojo

I have a cool bit of dojo running where I click a button and it brings a success message on the screen via JavaScript. Is it possible to issue a call to a server-side Groovy script (eg. `foo.groovy`) from within this JavaScript?

Not only do I want to show the cool success message, but I need to do some work in the background at that point also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some relevant links from the Dojo documentation:

- [Intro to AJAX and Dojo](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/ajax.html)
- [Dojo.xhrGet() reference](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/xhrGet.html): sends a GET request to the server-side resource (which can be a Groovy script or anything else that resides on the server). The live examples on this page are currently broken, but I'm told this is being resolved.
- [Dojo.xhrPost() reference](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/xhrPost.html#dojo-xhrpost): sends a POST request. There are variants for PUT and DELETE too.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to use dojo's AJAX call system.

Comment: It would be nice, if you would post some example code snippets of your solution, to give others an idea how this can be achieved.